# Why do windows API calls dealing with bytes (such as 'recv') use char*, which is signed by default?

Tags: c, recv, unsigned-char, uint8t

I'm fairly new to c/c++, and I'm trying to follow some guidelines which suggest using the stdint.h defined types where possible (`uint8_t`, etc instead of `unsigned char`).

However, it seems like when you're calling an API which expects a `char*` buffer (such as `recv`), you have to use whatever type that API dictates.

What I don't understand is why, if you're reading bytes, wouldn't you want it to be unsigned, so you get values between 0 and 255 instead of -128 and 127.

I don't know if this is implementation-specific, but I've only ever seen `char` default to signed.

Are you expected to cast the results of calls like this to an `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t*` to allow you to interpret the higher positive values?

Comment: SInce the calls only need a pointer, I don't suppose the original designers thought it mattered either way.

Comment: First to learn is there is no language C/C++, but only the two **different** languages C and C++. Said that, the C standard does not defined a specific signed-ness for `char` So this is a windows-matter. And the WinAPI is far from using modern C programming style; `stdint.h` was not avail when it was designed. And it probably does not even matter wheter `char` is signed or unsigned for those functions.

Comment: @Olaf Ah, ok.  So it is implementation-specific then?  And I just need to interpret it however makes sense for what I'm writing?

Comment: @Twicetimes: This is C bascis you will find answered in every good C book and - of course - the standard. It is not even clear what your problem is using `char`. If you don't do arithmetics, there is little to no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, `recv` is part of the Winsock API, which originated as a clone of the 4.2BSD sockets API. 4.2BSD predates ANSI C and the `void` keyword, so it uses `char *` because it was the closest thing to a generic pointer at the time.

Later, after `void` was invented, BSD and other Unix systems updated the definition of `recv`, and now they all use `void *`. The motivation for this change is clear: `char *` isn't really a generic pointer, using it as one makes your code uglier, with more casts. The `void *` version of `recv` mandated by POSIX too, so the only OS vendor that doesn't have it is the one that cares the least about POSIX compliance and code aesthetics... Microsoft.

Comment: So on the POSIX-compliant versions, you'd always be expected to have to cast it anyway?

Comment: No, with a `void *` you never need a cast. You can just pass any kind of pointer.

Comment: Ok, but when interpreting the results, presumably I need to cast to uint8_t or similar, otherwise when I try to read the byte values, I'd get -128 instead of 128, for example?

Comment: Thanks for the historical context btw.  Always helps to understand why things are the way they are now.

Comment: I don't know why you think you need an "interpreting" cast. If you want to receive a stream of `uint8_t`'s you can just make an array like `uint8_t a[1000];` and pass it directly to recv like `recv(s, a, sizeof a)` and then (after appropriate error checking on the return value) just go ahead and use `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ... no cast needed. If your recv takes a `char *` then you need just one cast `recv(s, (char *)a, sizeof a)`.

Comment: Right, it was the cast on the call I wasn't sure about.  Thanks.